# I need to get the date a file was created from a google apps script but im being told getDateCreated and getlastUpdated arent functions?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-docs

As the title suggest I have an Apps script where I need the Date created of the google doc but when i use the following code
''' var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("filename")
var final = file.getDateCreated()'''
I get told that getDateCreated isnt a function and the same issue happens with getlastUpdated can anyone point out what im missing. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`DriveApp.getFilesByName("filename")` returns a `FileIterator` not a File.  You need to iterate through the files, even if there is only one file with that name.

```
function test() {
  try {
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("filename");
    while( files.hasNext() ) {
      var file = files.next();
      console.log(file.getDateCreated());
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```